# Asp.net Core Razor Attendance Create Page is creating new employee while saving attendance time of an employee. How to fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

```
Database Used: MySql Server
DotNet Core Version = 2.2
Platform: Windows 10 IIS
```

When I am trying to save an attendance of an existing employee, the attendance page is trying to create a new employee with null values in Name fields. Since name field is set to not null its failed and showing error message.

Employee Table

```
namespace payroll_razor_core.Models.repository
{
    [Table("Employee")]
    [Display(Name = "Employee",Description = "Stores Employee Basic Details.")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [Column("Employee Id")]
        [Key]
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public string EmployeeName =>
            string.Concat(EmployeeFirstName, 
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmployeeMiddleName)?"":" "+EmployeeMiddleName,
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmployeeLastName) ? "" : " " + EmployeeLastName
            );

        [Column("Employee First Name")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name *")]
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Exceeded Character Limit..!!")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[[A-Za-z+[\s]+[A-Za-z]+]*]*", ErrorMessage = "Can accept only characters..!!",
            MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds = 1000)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee First Name is required..!!")]
        public string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }

        [Column("Employee Middle Name")]
        [Display(Name = "Middle Name *")]
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Exceeded Character Limit..!!")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[[A-Za-z+[\s]+[A-Za-z]+]*]*", ErrorMessage = "Can accept only characters..!!",
            MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds = 1000)]
        public string EmployeeMiddleName { get; set; }

        [Column("Employee Last Name")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name *")]
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Exceeded Character Limit..!!")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[[A-Za-z+[\s]+[A-Za-z]+]*]*", ErrorMessage = "Can accept only characters..!!",
            MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds = 1000)]
        public string EmployeeLastName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AttendanceDailyRegister> AttendanceDailyRegisters { get; set; }
    }
```

Attendance Table

```
[Table("Attendance")]
    [Display(Name = "Attendance",Description = "Registers Employee Attendance")]
    public class Attendance
    {

        [Key]
        [Column("Attendance Id")]
        [Display(Name = "Attendance Id")]
        public int AttendanceId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
        [Column("Employee")]
        [Display(Name = "Employee")]
        public string Employee { get; set; }

        public bool Check{ get; set; }

        [Column("AttendanceTime")]
        [Display(Name = "Attendance Time",AutoGenerateField = true)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dddd, dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm:ss tt}")]
        [Timestamp]
        public DateTime AttendanceTime { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Employee")]
        public virtual Employee Employees { get; set; }
    }
```

Attendance Create Page

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Data.payroll_app_context _context;

        public CreateModel(Data.payroll_app_context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
        ViewData["Employee"] = new SelectList(_context.Employee, "EmployeeId", "EmployeeName");
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public AttendanceDailyRegister AttendanceDailyRegister { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            //Commented for catching errors.
            /*if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }*/

            _context.AttendanceDailyRegister.Add(AttendanceDailyRegister);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
```

Attendance Razor CSHTML Page

```
@page
@model razor.Pages.attendance.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Attendance</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Attendance.Employee" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Attendance.Employee" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Employee"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Attendance.Check" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Attendance.Check)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Here in this page while saving new attendance time of an existing employee, its creating a new employee. I Cannot fix it. Please help me.

Comment: `_context.AttendanceDailyRegister.Add(AttendanceDailyRegister)` _adds_ the entity to the context. It does not automatically update an existing entity. You will have to retrieve the existing entity first and update that. Also note that you shouldn’t use your database models as request parameters as that will effectively open a lot of security holes. Use a separate model for the parameters you retrieve from your Razor page.

Comment: Ok. I will use seperate model for saving data. But the main problem here i am not trying to update an existing data. I am trying to save a new attendance data on basis of date for an existing employee. But instead its creating a new employee.

Comment: Then make sure that the Id of the new entity is not set, so that it is understood as a new entity.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The moment I changed the attendance table, the problem got solved. Though I don't clearly understand how it got solved.

```
[Table("Attendance")]
    [Display(Name = "Attendance",Description = "Registers Employee Attendance")]
    public class Attendance
    {

         private readonly Employee employee;
        [Key]
        [Column("Attendance Id")]
        [Display(Name = "Attendance Id")]
        public int AttendanceId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
        [Column("Employee")]
        [Display(Name = "Employee")]
        public string Employee { get; set; }

        public bool Check{ get; set; }

        [Column("AttendanceTime")]
        [Display(Name = "Attendance Time",AutoGenerateField = true)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dddd, dd/MM/yyyy, h:mm:ss tt}")]
        [Timestamp]
        public DateTime AttendanceTime { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Employee")]
        public virtual Employee Employees => employee
    }
```